# How to remove Schlage Lever Handle

Tags: doorknob

I can’t remove the handle.[image] I’ve tried inserting a small, flat screwdriver into the holes on the side but they won’t depress

Comment: Have you tried pushing on the little hoop while pulling the handle?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Just curious... is the hoop inside the hole on the side?  Hard to see in the photo provided.

Comment: Zoom in between the rosette and the handle. There’s a little indentation (well, a catch, really) that has a loop sticking out of the right side of it.

Comment: did you try removing the two screws?

Comment: pull on the wire loop while shaking the handle a bit .

Comment: Kinda looks to me like there's a little tab in that slot.